# Ionic - toast message not working inside 'loaderror' eventlistner function of inappbrowser

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I'm trying to show toast message when the given url fails to load in inappbrowser,
this is my code

```
function BrowserLoadError(event) {
        browser.close();
        loading.dismiss();
        this.toast.show("Can't Load the app", '3000', 'center').subscribe(
            toast => {
                console.log(toast);
            }
        );
        //alert("This App can't be reached now");
    }
```

but however its not working, the toast message is not showing, but it is displaying when we are calling from anyother place other than eventlistner function.

how to make it work within the function?

This is my full code

```
urlLink(data, target, options): void {
    let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        spinner: 'bubbles',
        content: 'Processing',
        duration: 5000
    });

    let browser = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(data, target, options);

    browser.hide();
    loading.present();
    browser.addEventListener('loaderror', BrowserLoadError);

    function BrowserLoadError(event) {
        browser.close();
        loading.dismiss();
        this.toast.show("Can't Load the app", '3000', 'center').subscribe(
            toast => {
                console.log(toast);
            }
        );
        //alert("This App can't be reached now");
    }
}
```

Comment: i would bet on `this` not being what you thought it would be here. Where is this function?

Comment: also why are you using `function` keyword?

Comment: I'm having the eventlistner like this "browser.addEventListener('loaderror', BrowserLoadError);"

Comment: I'm having the eventlistner and the function within a wrapper function,  i tried to have the eventlistner as a separate function outside of the wrapper function but the eventlistners are not working outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the mean time i too found the issue and fixed like this

```
let toast = new Toast();
toast.show("This App can't be launched now", '5000', 'bottom').subscribe(
    toast => {
        console.log(toast);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

After a little test, the problem comes actually that `this` is not your controller when used inside the error callback. Saving the reference in a variable should fix this (pun):

```
urlLink(data, target, options): void {
    let self = this; //save the reference before

    let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        spinner: 'bubbles',
        content: 'Processing',
        duration: 5000
    });

    let browser = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(data, target, options);

    browser.hide();
    loading.present();
    browser.addEventListener('loaderror', BrowserLoadError);

    function BrowserLoadError(event) {
        browser.close();
        loading.dismiss();
        //use your variable here
        self.toast.show("Can't Load the app", '3000', 'center').subscribe(
            toast => {
                console.log(toast);
            }
        );
        //alert("This App can't be reached now");
    }
}
```